# Implementing multiple Async/Array Tasks via Task.WhenAll (no LINQ)

Tags: c#, arrays, async-await, task-parallel-library, ienumerable

MSDN sample (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556530.aspx) demonstrates this technique of running multiple asynchronous I/O download operations using `Async/Await` construct and `LINQ` object library like shown in the following code snippet:

```
// Create a query. 
IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery = 
    from url in urlList select ProcessURLAsync(url);

// Use ToArray to execute the query and start the download tasks.
Task<int>[] downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();

int[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);


async Task<int> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client)
{
    byte[] byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    DisplayResults(url, byteArray);
    return byteArray.Length;
}
```

I am looking for a simple alternative implementing the same functionality **without LINQ**, i.e. replacing these two lines with some core Generics/Array C# methods:

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery = from url in urlList select ProcessURLAsync(url);
Task<int>[] downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fairly simple:

```
var taskList = new List<Task<int>>();
foreach(var url in urlList) {
  taskList.Add(ProcessURLAsync(url));
}

Task<int>[] downloadTasks = taskList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Very compact solution and works like a charm, thanks! I've slightly modified it by adding a CancellationToken, but core functionality remains the same. Best regards,